# Regex tester is pulling through the GUID from href, but in debug sampler its showing as null value in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

Regex is functioning when I test in the regex tester but If i use that regex and check the debug sampler its pulling through null value.

Regex used: [a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12} to identify the GUID in a href (example: href="/path/a4d39756-b4a6-40e2-a29c-00f2e62c5c58" )

This is the complete HTML from which im trying to read the GUID : `<a class="btn btn--primary btn--btn-sm mt-3" href="/path/a4d39756-b4a6-40e2-a29c-00f2e62c5c58">path</a>`

[Regular expression extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9pTb.png)
As you can see in the image the first value its reading as null but its capturing the GUID in the subsequent one's [Debug Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rxSN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with regular expression `href="/path/(.+?)"`

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Sunny, It did work :)